# POSH created Items and BusinessData fields not displaying additional ECT fields

Tags: powershell, external-content-type, business-data-catalog, item-updating

I have a POSH script that create items on a list that pulls additional field data from a BCS source.  The function is as follows.

```
Function Add-SPItems($TargetingDetails)
{
$site = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($TargetingDetails.List.URL)
$web = $site.OpenWeb()
$list = $web.Lists[$TargetingDetails.List.Name]

ForEach($Add in $TargetingDetails."Item Updates")
{
    $NewItem = $list.AddItem()
    ForEach($Key in $Add.GetEnumerator().name)
    {            
        if($NewItem.Fields[$Key].TypeAsString -eq "BusinessData")
        {
            $NewItem[([Microsoft.SharePoint.SPBusinessDataField]($NewItem.Fields[$Key])).InternalName] = $Add.$Key
            $NewItem[([Microsoft.SharePoint.SPBusinessDataField]($NewItem.Fields[$Key])).RelatedField] = [Microsoft.SharePoint.BusinessData.Infrastructure.EntityInstanceIdEncoder]::EncodeEntityInstanceId([System.Object]@($Add.$Key))
        }else{
            $NewItem[$Key]=$Add.$Key
        }
    }
    $NewItem.Update()
    }

$web.Dispose()
}
```

I feed this function a `HashTable` like...

```
[pscustomobject]@{
        Name = "Add New Item to SP List"
        ;Description = "Add all of the new Items into the SP list"
        ;"Action Type" = "Add-SPItems"
        ;List = 
        [pscustomobject]@{
            Name = "My List"
            ;URL = "https://MYSP/sites/Dev_Site/Lists/Target_List"
        }
        ;"Item Updates" = [pscustomobject]@(
           Title="Manufacturing Details"
           ;"Date Ingested"=(get-date).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ssZ")
           ;"Industry Name"="Manufacturing"
           ;"Industry Code"=[int]123
           ;"ECT Field"=[int]12345
          )
    }
```

The only way I have been able to get it start pulling in the additional BCS field data is to manually open and close the item.  I have attempted an additional POSH update of the item (with and without content change) and SPWorkflow (again, with and without content change).

It seems like there has to be a method to trigger this not through the GUI given that the GUI is just a front end for code.  What gives?

Comment: As a workaround, I added a function to get all of the associated fields and values of the ECT and dump them into a datatable.  I then added a loop to write all of the additional field data from the datatable into the list item fields that exist.

The issue with this, of course, is that this is still static so that if the data changes on the source those changes will not be reflected on the list item's ECT fields until the list item is updated and proper synchronization begins occurring.